# multiple exceptions being thrown in intelliJ on junit testing

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, exception, repository

So I am debugging this application that is returning null on emails in the Login method. When using Postman to check data. I am using IntelliJ. My userbean works, but when I try to use the repository it blows up with several exceptions.

```
public UserServiceBean login(UserServiceBean userServiceBean) {
    //set the flag to false
    userServiceBean.setSuccess(false);

        User user =
                userRepository
                        .findByUsernameAndPassword(
                                userServiceBean.getUsername(),
                                userServiceBean.getPassword());
        if(null != user) {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userServiceBean);
            userServiceBean.setSuccess(true);
        }

    return userServiceBean;
```

I am first time ever trying to write Junit testing for this code, I am completely lost on why this isn't working. We are using Java8, mongoDB and Springboot...

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import edu.team3.cocktailapp.beans.UserServiceBean;
import edu.team3.cocktailapp.models.User;
import edu.team3.cocktailapp.repositories.UserRepository;
import edu.team3.cocktailapp.services.UserService;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
```

I think my repository isn't working right?? Or maybe its coded wrong?? Most of the errors were with MongoDB regarding the repository-
[Errors thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vVJA.png)

```
@SpringBootTest
class CocktailappApplicationTests {

@Autowired
UserRepository repository;


@Test
void testUserService() {
    //testing login
    UserService service = new UserService();
    UserServiceBean bean = new UserServiceBean();
    bean.setEmail("bean@testing");
    bean.setUsername("Frank");
    bean.setPassword("password");
    assertEquals(bean.getUsername(), "Frank");
    assertEquals(bean.getEmail(), "bean@testing");
    assertEquals(bean.getPassword(), "password");
    //testing repository
    repository.save(
            new User(
                    bean.getUsername(),
                    bean.getEmail(),
                    bean.getPassword()
            )
    );

    UserServiceBean login = service.login(bean);
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated-

Comment: You have to mock the repository interface otherwise it will throw exception.

Comment: Then you can mock the repository.save() call.

Comment: Mockito.when(repository.save(any())).thenReturn(null);

Comment: thank you so much I will give it a try :) I am so new to App dev, I just did backend, I have been trolling Stackoverflow for help-